# django-filter - How to parse field name with suffix such as "_id" (dynamic field names)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I would like to be able to parse a query string's params by the name as well as the value. Is this possible with `django-filters` or `django-rest-framework`?

Example: `/api/user/?custom_field_{id}={value}`

```
class UserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    custom_field{id} = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(
        queryset=CustomField.objects.all(), method="filter_by_custom_field"
    )

    def filter_by_custom_field(self, queryset, name, value):
        # How can I get access to the {id} as well as the value in here?
        pass
```

The above syntax is not allowed (`custom_field{id}`), but it is an example to show what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get parameters from GET/POST request then you need to retrieve them by processing request in your view:

```
class Test(View):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        vote_value = self.request.POST.get('parameter_name', 0)
```

Same happens for GET, just change method name after `self.request`.